# Framebuffer and Textures Non Power Of Two

Tags: glsl, opengl-2.0

I've seen some tutorials where they attach to a framebuffer, a texture that is a power of two. In other tutorials I have seen that texture is not power of two.

My question is: Does affect performance when I to attach a texture that is not a power of two to a framebuffer, or can I use a texture of any size?

The same in the function glRenderbufferStorage, can it affect if my texture is not power of two?

Comment: Note in some (older) OpenGL versions textures are limited to "power-of-two". e.g in all the versions before OpenGL 2.0 or textures with mipmaps in OpenGL ES 2.0. See alos [WebGL and OpenGL Differences](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/WebGL_and_OpenGL_Differences#Non-Power_of_Two_Texture_Support)

Comment: Mmm, but I've seen examples where it is used with versions 3.x

Comment: That is a comment and not an answer  to your question.

Comment: Sorry, but then I do not understand the purpose of your comment.

Comment: One reason for "power-of-two" textures is compatibility to "older" hardware and earlier versions of OpenGL.